# Basic question about algebra for relative demand.

Tags: economics

Suppose I have two markets, Home and Foreign. Suppose that

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{c_2^F}{c_1^F}$$

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{c_2^H}{c_1^H}$$

Supposedly I am supposed to be able to show

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{c_2^F + c_2^H}{c_1^F+ c_1^H}$$

But by rules of simple algebra, it would seem

$$\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{c_2^Fc_1^H+c_1^Fc_2^H}{2c_1^Fc_1^H}$$

**MY QUESTION:**
What step am I missing to get
$$\frac{p_1}{p_2} = \frac{c_2^F + c_2^H}{c_1^F+ c_1^H}$$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using algebra you get that both expressions are the same:
$$(c_2^F+c_2^H)/(c_1^F+c_1^H)=(c_2^Fc_1^H+c_1^Fc_2^H)/(2c_1^Fc_1^H)$$
operating:
$$2c_1^Fc_1^Hc_2^F+2c_1^Fc_1^Hc_2^H=c_2^F(c_1^H)^2+c_1^Hc_1^Fc_2^H+c_2^Fc_1^Hc_1^F+(c_1^F)^2c_2^H$$
then:
$$c_1^Fc_1^Hc_2^F+c_1^Fc_1^Hc_2^H=c_2^F(c_1^H)^2+(c_1^F)^2c_2^H $$ 
looking the first two equalities, we get  :
$$c_1^Fc_2^H=c_2^Fc_1^H$$
replace that in our last equality and you get that both expressions are the same.
Reversing the steps deliver you to get the "not so common" equality.
It's a little tricky.